# Windows cannot access \\PC_NAME

Tags: networking, windows-11, shared-folders

When I try to access a PC shared folder under NETWORK, I get the error below:

*"You do not have permission to access \PC_NAME contact your network administrator to request access"*

But when I manually enter the address in File Explorer `\\PC_NAME\d\` it works.

[image: screenshot]

I want to view all the shared folders when I click on a `PC_NAME` under Network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal sharing approach is to share the folder, and that is what succeeded in your second try.

Mapping just the computer (with no special sharing) was deprecated some years back.

If you wish, you can name the drive and share it to the user you wish. Then you can access the entire drive.  I do this and it works fine. You can see all the folders in the drive.

Naming and Sharing are in the Drive properties.

[image: Windows 11 Drive Sharing]